# Conditional filter for visitor role

Tags: views, users, blocks

I'm throwing a big number of views showing a list of 'events' (nodes) happening today, tomorrow and after tomorrow. I'd like registered users with role 'editor' could see all events from today (not only until after tomorrow).

Ideally it would be something like this:

- if user (visitor) == editor -> filter: date >= today
- else filter: date >= today && date <= +2 days

In other words:

- filter:  date >= today
- if user (visitor) != editor -> filter (AND): date <= +2 days

The idea is to be able to add some filters depending on the visitors role (not the node creator one).

Is it possible making use of default views panel?

Otherwise I'd have to duplicate + modify filter + modify permissions + add in block design list some dozens! of blocks.

Comment: _I post it first as a comment. Then if no better solution is suggested I'll post it as the answer to my own question._

One way to 'solve' i would be to set the view with the most generic query (only filter: date >= today) and then shorten the offer of 'events' (nodes) shown via conditional twig in the own theme template file. I only can see 2 cons to it:
1. not all the control is in the own views panel
2. depending on use of cache processing the webpage will take longer as the query in the view will ask in all cases for the broadest list of results

Comment: I would add a contextual filter for the date field and then provide the filter limits as arguments. If you don't render the Views yourself use [hook_views_pre_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_view).

Comment: Instead of having a custom solution, did you consider managing it from the views UI? You clone your view and have different configs to the filter, then assign permissions to each view. I think this is easier to maintain.

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf Ty but as mentioned it is a large number of views/blocks and it would suppose a massive number of extra blocks that specially in the list of block placements would be very hard to keep.

Comment: @4uk4 Ty! Not sure how to proceed with it but I'll give it a look

Comment: @apaderno I've seen you've edited my post. Thank you as I'm sure it makes it more correct. Anyway I believe the key word 'Views' should remain in the title as the question relates to the Views panel and how to create/modify a view in order to achieve what I'm after. Is it possible to bring that back? T.I.A.

Comment: @hip It's useless to put *Views* in the title, since the question is tagged [tag:views]. We don't use tags nor *Drupal* in titles.

Comment: I didn't know. Sorry & thank you @apadermo